# Password Reset throws 'Something went wrong while resetting customer password' error

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1.7

It is happening with one of my customer's password reset and not an issue for rest. It shows 'Something went wrong while resetting customer password' error whenever I try to reset the customer's password. I did reset the time interval of password reset option but no use. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a generic error message for end user, Can you check your error logs where you will see the actual reason why you are not able to reset the customer password.

Answer (score 0):

Please set below configuration and than you can reset passwords if below condition satisfies your request.
suppose you have set 10(in minutes) than make sure second request will be done after 10 minutes.
Time between password resets from admin is configured in Stores->Configuration->Advanced->Admin->Security->Min Time Between Password Reset Requests

also make sure cron job is working in your web store.

Thanks

Comment: I tried that. After the interval, the password reset is working for other customers (sending password reset links successfully) but it is not working with one of the customers email. As you know if we try to reset the password before the interval time completes, it throws different error('too many password reset requests').

Comment: Please wait for some time to send request because all requests are in queue. one by one request get executed.

Comment: @Meetanshi, I think this answer is related to admin part, means reset password for admin not customer.